# Maximal ideals and principal ideals domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, and an ideal $I = ( p(x) )$ of $R[x]$.

Then consider the statement:
*" $I$ is a maximal ideal if and only if $p(x)$ is irreducible "*

Does that statement need the hypothesis *"$R[x]$ is a principal ideals domain"* to be true? Or is that statement true anyway?

Comment: @DietrichBurde In what way is the link you provide the same as OP's question?

Comment: Sorry, I meant [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593553/px-irreducible-polynomial-iff-j-langle-px-rangle-is-a-maximal-ideal-in). The domain needs to be a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $p(x)$ is not the zero polynomial and is reducible, then there exists some non-constant polynomial such that $q(x)\mid p(x)\implies (p(x))\subsetneq (q(x))\ne R[x]$, so $(p(x))$ is not maximal. This proves the forward direction.

For the other direction, suppose $p(x)\subsetneq J$, some proper ideal of $R[x]$, and that $p(x)$ is irreducible. Then we must have $(p(x),q(x))\subset J$ whence $q(x)$ is coprime to $p(x)$. By Bézout's identity, $\exists a(x),b(x)\in R[x]$ such that $a(x)p(x)+b(x)q(x)=1\in J$, but then $J=R[x]$, a contradiction. So $p(x)$ is reducible in fact, which proves the statement.

Comment: But Bezout Identity is not true in any UFD. You need a PID to use it

Comment: Then you just answered your own question.

Comment: I was wondering if there was an alternative proof to show the other implication without using the Bezout Identity since I cannot find a counterexample of a R[x] not PID in which p(x) is irreducible but (p(x)) is not maximal.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832866/must-an-ideal-generated-by-an-irreducible-element-be-a-maximal-ideal

Comment: There's a counterexample given by @DietrichBurde.

Answer (score 1):

Tne statement is actually **false** even if $R$ is a PID.

E.g. consider the case $R=\Bbb Z$ and the chain of prime ideals with proper inclusions
$$
(0)\subset(x)\subset(2,x).
$$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. The hypothesis I wanted to refer was R[x] is a PID (instead of R)

Comment: @LourdesLB, well, $R[x]$ is a PID only when $R$ is a field. Indeed if $r\in R$ is a non-invertible element the ideal $(r,x)$ is not principal.